# Prove that $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)\sin(\pi s)$ is bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $f(s)=\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)\sin(\pi s)$ is bounded.

Is there an easy way to show that this function is bounded?

Edit: Actually I want to prove this to prove Euler’s reflection formula of Gamma function.

And I see there are a lot of proof based on Weierstrass product, integral calculations.

My plan is

to show this entire and bounded, then

by Liouiville, it is a constant.

so it must be $\pi$.

All I know is that $\Gamma$ can be meromorphically continued to entire complex plane with singularities at $0, -1, -2,\dots$.

Edit(2):

Here is what I've tried:

Since $\Gamma(s)$ has simple poles at $s=0,-1,-2,\dots$,

$\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)$ has simple poles at $ s \in \mathbb{Z}$,

and $\sin(\pi s)$ has a zero at $ s \in \mathbb{Z}$ and no poles, so

$f(s)= \Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)\sin(\pi s)$ is entire.

And I have no idea how to show that $f(s)$ is bounded.

Comment: Prove [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) and the result follows. Hint - this function is constant.

Comment: It is immediate from the meromorphic continuation that the poles of $\Gamma(s)$ are simple at $-n$ of residue $(-1)^n/n!$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: As easy as pi(e), maybe?

Comment: @K.defaoite actually the converse way is what I’d like to show.

Comment: What facts can you assume about $\Gamma(s)$, including your definition of $\Gamma(s)$ (as a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$)? Note that the functional equation $\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$ alone cannot prove the fact, since there are many other meromorphic functions $g$ for which $g(s+1)=sg(s)$ and $g(1)=1$ holds true but $g(s)g(1-s)\sin(\pi s)$ is unbounded. (For instance, consider $g(s)=\Gamma(s)\exp(e^{2\pi i s}-1)$.) This shows that we must utilize some other properties of $\Gamma$. And this is why it is crucial to know what other properties of $\Gamma$ you are going to allow.

Comment: @SangchulLee I didn't notice that. thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @SangchulLee then can you tell me what kind of properties are necessary? since I don't know the context...

Comment: I actually believe that showing $f(s)$ is bounded is no simpler than showing that $f(s)$ is constant. That is, you will somehow need to study the behavior of $\Gamma(s)$, and in doing so, you won't be able to avoid employing some of computations you wanted to avoid at the beginning. (However, we may still try to minimize computation load.)

Comment: https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2019fa/LectureNotes17.pdf I found this(p.4~5), it show that $f(s)$ is constant.